Unable to use the treemap.js module with highcharts V11.4
There's a specific graph I need called a 'treemap with a colour axis' which requires two modules. treemap.js and heatmap.js.
I've tried a few different methods but I keep getting strange errors when I try to include them in my project such as:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at pushUnique (script?v=vX17qqiPDxzKs18Nj2Vt_4PDjBMkk_DMrxvt8ZpUlvY1:47720:323)
    at x.compose (treemap.js:8:2115)
    at treemap.js:8:25053
    at i (treemap.js:8:368)
    at treemap.js:8:24845
    at treemap.js:8:219
    at treemap.js:8:271

I've tried including both modules when it lazy loads the page:
lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
    return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
        name: 'HerdManagementWeb',
        files: [
            'https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js',
            'https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js',
            url("/version/resource?path=~/bundles/milkcomposition&ext=.js")
        ]
    }]);
}]

I've also tried downloading the modules myself and including them in the script bundle:
scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/libraries/highcharts11/heatmap.js");
scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/libraries/highcharts11/treemap.js");

Same problem as before, treemap doesn't work.
I figured maybe treemap is already included in the highcharts module, so I removed the treemap.js module and it complains that I don't have treemap:
Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=treemap
 - missingModuleFor: treemap

So if it won't let me download the correct file, it won't load it via the direct link provided by HighCharts in their own documentation and treemap is not included in the HighCharts module, what am I supposed to do?

To use the Highcharts Heatmap, you only need to import the heatmap module like this:
import HC_heatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
HC_heatmap(Highcharts);

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-yah6kg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
To use the Highcharts Treemap, you only need to import the Treemap module. However, if you want to use the colorAxis as well, you also need to import the Heatmap module. You can read more about it here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap
import HC_treemap from 'highcharts/modules/treemap';
import HC_heatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';

HC_treemap(Highcharts);
HC_heatmap(Highcharts);

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-shqwvd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This didn't resolve the issue, the heatmap module by itself works just fine, its specifically the treemap module that isn't being loaded correctly

Check out the second demo in my answer. The treemap module loads correctly and works without any issues. Did you try loading it the same way?

The project I'm working on is structured a little differently to yours but the module is included in the script bundle. The heatmap module works fine in this configuration, just not treemap for whatever reason.

Are you getting any errors in the console? I'd love to help but I'm afraid I need some more details of how your project is configured so I could reproduce it on my machine.

I'll try and add some more context to the post

If you're not getting an error "missingModuleFor: treemap", then it's loaded correctly. Furthermore we need to investigate the other parts of the code that might break the chart. My suggestions for now: 1) Please try to simplify your project as much as possible to check if the simplest treemap chart displays. 2) Please share your chart config with us - maybe on the stackblitz we'll be able to reproduce your errors.
